# Instability of FindRoot solution

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Using `FindRoot` on a smooth function of a parameter and a variable, the resulting solution should be a smooth function of the parameter, by the Implicit Function Theorem. However, Mathematica returns a very spiky unstable function. One way to fix the problem seems to avoid Newton's method. Are there others, in particular that work with more than one variable?

MWE:

```
Clear[cdf, s0, s, sol]
cdf[x_] := -2 (x - Sinh[1/2] + 
     Sinh[1/2 - x])/(-2 (1 - Sinh[1/2] + Sinh[1/2 - 1]))
s0[a_] := 
 s0[a] = x /. FindRoot[D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x] == 0, {x, 0.5}]
Plot[s0[a], {a, 0, 1}]
(*A different root finding method does not cause instability.*)
s[a_] := s[a] = 
  x /. FindRoot[D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x] == 0, {x, 0.01, 0.99}]
Plot[s[a], {a, 0, 1}]
(*The problem is worse with two variables*)
sol[c_] := 
 sol[c] = {p1, p2} /. 
   FindRoot[{D[p1*(cdf[p2 - p1] - cdf[p1]), p1] == 0, 
 D[(p2 - c)*(1 - cdf[p2 - p1]), p2] == 0}, {{p1, 0.2}, {p2, 0.5}}]
Plot[{sol[c][[1]], sol[c][[2]]}, {c, 0, 1}]
(*Using non-Newton methods of root finding does not help with two
variables.*)
sol[c_] := 
 sol[c] = {p1, p2} /. 
   FindRoot[{D[p1*(cdf[p2 - p1] - cdf[p1]), p1] == 0, 
     D[(p2 - c)*(1 - cdf[p2 - p1]), p2] == 0}, {{p1, 0.1, 0.8}, {p2, 
      0.2, 0.9}}]
Plot[{sol[c][[1]], sol[c][[2]]}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) is sensitive to having a good starting value.

```
Clear[cdf, s0]

cdf[x_] := -2 (x - Sinh[1/2] + 
     Sinh[1/2 - x])/(-2 (1 - Sinh[1/2] + Sinh[1/2 - 1]))
s0[a_] := s0[a] = x /. FindRoot[D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x] == 0, {x, 0.5}]

Plot[s0[a], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The fist part of the plot suggests that a lower starting value is needed, e.g., `{x, 0.1}`

```
Clear[cdf, s0]

cdf[x_] := -2 (x - Sinh[1/2] + 
     Sinh[1/2 - x])/(-2 (1 - Sinh[1/2] + Sinh[1/2 - 1]))
s0[a_] := s0[a] = x /. FindRoot[D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x] == 0, {x, 0.1}]

Plot[s0[a], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Likewise for the two variable case:

```
Clear[sol]

sol[c_] := 
 sol[c] = {p1, p2} /. 
   FindRoot[{D[p1*(cdf[p2 - p1] - cdf[p1]), p1] == 0, 
     D[(p2 - c)*(1 - cdf[p2 - p1]), p2] == 0}, {{p1, 0.2}, {p2, 0.5}}]

Plot[{sol[c][[1]], sol[c][[2]]}, {c, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.75, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

The plot suggests better starting values might be `{{p1, 0.1}, {p2, 0.9}}`

```
Clear[sol]

sol[c_] := 
 sol[c] = {p1, p2} /. 
   FindRoot[{D[p1*(cdf[p2 - p1] - cdf[p1]), p1] == 0, 
     D[(p2 - c)*(1 - cdf[p2 - p1]), p2] == 0}, {{p1, 0.1}, {p2, 0.9}}]

Plot[{sol[c][[1]], sol[c][[2]]}, {c, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.75, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I like using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) for problems like this. Let's take your first example:

```
cdf[x_] := -2(x - Sinh[1/2] + Sinh[1/2 - x])/(-2 (1 - Sinh[1/2] + Sinh[1/2 - 1]))

eqn = D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x] == 0;
```

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), we need an ODE and an initial condition. The initial condition can be obtained by solving the equation for a particular value of `a`:

```
x0 = x /. FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. a->0], {x, 1}]
```

> 2.98238*10^-16

The ODE is obtained by differentiating the equation with respect to the parameter `a`:

```
ode = D[eqn /. x->x[a], a];
```

Putting these together we have:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, x[0] == x0}, x, {a, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

For your second example we have:

```
eqn = {
    D[p1*(cdf[p2 - p1] - cdf[p1]), p1] == 0, 
    D[(p2 - c)*(1 - cdf[p2 - p1]), p2] == 0
};
```

Initial condition:

```
{p10, p20} = {p1, p2} /. FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. c->0], {p1, .1}, {p2, 1}]
```

> {0.114562, 0.83039}

ODE:

```
deqn = D[eqn /. {p1 -> p1[c], p2 -> p2[c]}, c];
```

Using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{deqn, p1[0] == p10, p2[0] == p20}, {p1, p2}, {c, 0, 1}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[Through @ sol[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ContourPlot shows you the solutions

```
gl[x_, a_]  = Evaluate[D[x*(cdf[a - x] - cdf[x]), x]] 
cp=ContourPlot[gl[x, a] == 0, {a, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1/2},FrameLabel -> {a, x}]
```

[image]

The solutions can be evaluated using `NDSolve`

```
sol[a_] := NSolve[{ gl[x, a] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x , Reals][[1]]

Show[{cp, ListPlot[Table[{a, x /. sol[a]}, {a, 0, 2, .1}]]}]
```

[image]

`solF[a_] := FindRoot[{ gl[x, a] == 0 }, {x, .5, 0, 1}  ]` give the same results!

Comment: The solutions work for 1 variable, upvoted. `solF[a_] := FindRoot` puts some dots off the curve for me, but the curve is smooth. The `NSolve`...`Show` method is very slow for 2 variables, I have not obtained the results yet. Using `Evaluate`...`ContourPlot3D` gives `Could not converge`... and other errors for 2 variables - I need to work on correcting the code to check whether this method can deal with 2+ variables.